# Split words contained in string based on uppercase

Tags: lua

I have a string that has no spaces, what marks every single word is the uppercase letter at the beginning of each word, what would be the best way for extracting them?

here's what i've got:

```
str = "TheseAreAFewWordsAndThis-one-contains-wildcards"
```

Desired output would be:

```
These
Are
A
Few
Words
And
This-one-contains-wildcards
```

I don't need to treat any magical characters as such, they can stay in the string no problems

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for wrd in str:gmatch("%u%U*") do print(wrd) end
```

`"%u%U*"` is a string pattern that matches a single capital letter followed by any number of non capital letter characters.

Please read https://www.lua.org/manual/5.4/manual.html#6.4.1

Comment: Thanks for the snippet, just to clarify, i read that `%u` does identify all uppercase letters, what does `%U*` actually do?

Comment: from the manual "the corresponding uppercase letter represents the complement of the class"  hence `%U` is a non-capital-letter character`  and `*` is zero or more (greedy)

Comment: Thank you very much, this made things very clear